# Specifying an IdentityFile with SSH

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I am trying to make a more streamlined means to establish an SSH client connection to a remote server.  I have created a public/private keypair and used `ssh-copy-id` to install the public key onto the remote server.

However, it still was asking for the password unless I put in the path for the identity file with something like `ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host`. Should I have to type this to bypass the password with public key authentication?

To bypass this I used `.bashrc` and created an alias using this path. However, is this the way to do this? Or is it just a question of the server allowing the public key so I can just use the usual `ssh user@host`?

Answer (score 103):

If you are able to successfully use keypair authentication with `ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host`, you can easily automate this with your SSH client configuration.

For example, if you add this to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host hostname
  User username
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
  IdentitiesOnly yes # see comment in answer below
```

You can then simply `ssh hostname`, and your username and identity file settings will be handled by your `config` file and you're off to the races, as they say.

The `IdentityFile` directive (which the `-i` switch for `ssh` overrides) has a default setting which will look for `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`, and `~/.ssh/id_rsa`; any other filenames for private keys must be specified in the `config` file or with `-i` on the command line.

If you add `IdentityFile` to your ssh config, you'll find that the client still sends the default key (see `ssh -vv` output). This can be problematic when using sites like github with multiple accounts. You'll need to include `IdentitiesOnly yes` if you want ssh to use only the key you've specified.

Comment: I created '~/.ssh/config' like this:                                                                    Host <server name>
  Hostname <ip address>
  User <username>
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<Identity File>                                                                       But when I 'ssh <server name> I receive "Bad owner or permissions on /home/benny/.ssh/config"

Comment: Can the login user be different to the key user? (like adding a key on the server for user USER, but using it for login as ROOT)?

Comment: Private keys are held by the user logging in; public keys are held by the account being logged into.  So long as the user's private key matches one of the `authorized_keys` in the remote account, you should be fine.  In other words, for `user`'s key to work for both `remoteuser` and `root`, both of the latter two must have `user`'s public key in their own `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: @Troy read the message carefully: the most common issue is that the file permissions for the key are too broad.

Comment: @Troy I think this is too late but config permissions should be strict according to the manual. 600 is just fine (`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`)

Comment: `IdentitiesOnly` directive saved my day. I was getting `too much login attempts` error because ssh client was sending other keys that I have before the correct one.

Comment: Interesting part about SSH sending other keys. Mine does not do this, it sends directly the key I've specified. In the `-vv` log, it says: `debug1: Will attempt key: my-key.pem  explicit` . `OpenSSH_9.0p1` on MacOS

Comment: It's quite possible that in the years since I first penned this answer, the default value of `IdentitiesOnly` got flipped from `No` to `Yes` in some distributions' `ssh_config`s. (: